# How to use htmlText as Radio button label in Flex 3

Tags: actionscript-3, flex3, radio-button

I need to show few words in bold for radio buttons in Flex 3. something like the following:

option 1: Hello **world.**

option 2: **Hello** world.

I see that there is no htmlText property for label of Radio Button. Anyone has any suggestions in accomplishing this requirement?

Thanks

Anji

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Timofei Davydik

You can include HTML Text inside RadioButton labels by extending RadioButton and overriding the updateDisplayList function. You need to change htmlText propert of textField to label's value inside this function.

Here is the HTMLRadioButton Component

```
package components
{

import mx.controls.RadioButton;

public class HTMLRadioButton extends RadioButton
{
  public function HTMLRadioButton()
  {
    super();
  }

   override protected function updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth:Number,
                                              unscaledHeight:Number):void
   {
        super.updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth, unscaledHeight);
        textField.htmlText = label;

   }
}
}
```

**Update:**

If you need multiline HTML in RadioButton label, then you need to extend this [component](http://code.google.com/p/vizierfx/source/browse/trunk/Vizier/src/components/MultilineRadioButton.as?r=7) in the same way as above.

Comment: Why didn't I see, that IUITextField includes ITextFieldInterface with htmlText property :) No doubt, that's great solution, thanks!